# How to connect from docker to database, which is running in the same local network with host machine?

Tags: database, docker, networking

I have two servers. First - with docker and certain container. Second - with database.
These servers are in one local network. I want to connect to second server's database from container running on first server.

I would like to solve it using docker network, but i have no idea what should i do.

Comment: Usually you don't need to do anything special, just use the DNS FQDN of the external database server as normal.  Do you have a [mcve] showing a case that's failing, including any error message you get?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I haven't tried it before. I thought it is hard to do.
Do you have any references about networking between containers and local servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i figured out. It is possible out of the box using network driver "bridge".
By default, containers connect to network with driver "bridge", which allow connections from docker container by ip in host's local network.

Example:

First server with postgres in container has 192.168.0.4 local ip. We should use port forwarding to allow connections by 192.168.0.4:5432.

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb postgres:latest
```

Second server with postgres in container has 192.168.0.3 local ip.
From inside this container connection by host local ip - works

```
psql --username="admin" --host="192.168.0.4" --dbname="mydb"
```

Removing network bridge from second server's container disallows connections like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example connecting a DB to another container, like described at documentation

Reference: [multi container](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/)

Comment: It is about connection between containers in one docker network. Not my case.

> If two containers are on the same network, they can talk to each other. If they aren’t, they can’t.